# angularjs binding nbsp entity doesnt work in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I'm using ng-bind-html in a table cell and I want the cell not to collapse when the binded value is an empty string ('').

So I bind to: `value || '&nbsp;'`

This works well on Crome and FF but fails on IE. If I check the source code on IE, it appears as a white-space.

Here's my fiddle showing this bug:

http://jsfiddle.net/Yq85R/8/

Thanks

Comment: Seems like it is trimmed somehow , but why only in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a CSS style issue:

Try this:

```
table td{
    border:1px solid;
   white-space: pre; 
}
```

Here is a sample fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Yq85R/10/

What `white-space: pre` does is to preserved whitespace.

Here is the documentation associated with this issue:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531182(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot man.
Can't up vote your answer cause don't have enough rep yet :(

[Up Vote]